# Migrating Django application from heroku (celery/redis) to aws fargate/lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, celery, aws-fargate

Apologies in advance for my little knowledge of AWS

I'm trying to draw parallels between my current setup on Heroku to a move to AWS. I've run into some memory issues on Heroku because of some machine learning models I'm running and Heroku seems too expensive for my needs.

I was recommenced to move to aws using fargate which would be a better fit for my app. Below is my whole architecture, I'm hoping for some guidance on my direction of what I have and where I plan to go.

A django application running on heroku.

The base of functionality is the user uploads a video from their mobile device and uploads it to s3. A message from SNS is sent to my Heroku server that the upload is completed. The server kicks off a celery task that downloads the video from s3 and uses a machine learning model to do some natural language processing, then saves the results to my postresql database. Obviously this is very compute intensive, so I've run into some memory issues and can for-see scaling issues to come.

After lots of tweaking and attempts to no avail, I've decided to move over to AWS and leverage some of the cost benefits that I've seen in comparison to heroku of running more memory intensive tasks.

I should also mention there is a web interface involved with this django project and it isn't just a REST Api.

As far as AWS goes, I'm looking for a bit of direction. Possibly just a rough outline of the architecture I should look deeper into.

My first plan is to dockerize my application and go from there...but I'm a bit stuck on how my application fits (website, rest api, worker threads) into the AWS ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

AWS is a great fit for the application you describe.  AWS Fargate / RDS will host your Django application.  You have the option of using AWS Batch to handle your processing.  One huge advantage is the ability to scale according to the needs of your application.

This image is one possible way to structure your application.  It's a lot of work to get to this point, but AWS offers a lot of power and flexibility for reasonable costs IMO.

[image: Fargate architecture]

Comment: I considering deploying my app like this. I am trying to estimate the costs. Can you perhaps give your five cents and tell me how much an APP with around 10000 CRUD requests a day would cost me plus 500 to 1000 Celery tasks?

Comment: VPC and RDS are the most costly elements.  Fargate / EC2 should be lower costs for smaller transactions but you may need to consider resilience.  Check out the AWS Cost Explorer but I would guess you would be looking at low hundreds USD per month.  You could look at Batch Fargate instead of Celery to avoid the overhead of running a dedicated EC2 instance for Celery

Comment: the diagram above is out-of-date because now you can submit jobs to Batch via VPC endpoints, so you don't need a lambda function